# Командная строка netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Доброго времени суток! Возник следующий вопрос, указал в командной строке netbeans два аргумента (оба текстовые файлы), пытаюсь открыть их через BufferedReader'ы выдаёт ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException 
Код:

1

```
BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
```

2

```
BufferedWriter fileWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(args[1]));
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему он не видит эти файлы? Может стоит как то по-особенному их указывать в качестве аргументов командной строки? 
Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А если сделать вместо `args[0]` и `args[1]` то, что на самом деле должно быть, тогда что? Может просто их содержание неверно? Как аргументы прописывали, Properties - Run?

Comment: Да, аргументы так прописывал, скорее всего в содержимом, сейчас кое-что исправлю.
Вроде файлы просто через строки передал - что-то получилось. Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Не за что, я и не ответил даже)) файлы - пути к файлам наверно.